# Rails 5 - vendor assets are not loaded on production (fonts only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5

It's perfectly working in development, but not in production. It's not finding the following files:

> /assets/fontello.woff
>   /assets/fontello.ttf

Here is the setup:

1. fonts files:

[image]

2. `assets.rb`

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
   ```
3. `fontello.css`

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'fontello';
       src: url('/assets/fontello.eot');
       src: url('/assets/fontello.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/assets/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/assets/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/assets/fontello.svg#fontello') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

As I said, everything is working fine in development. I have try a lot of things. For example:

1. moving the fonts in the public folder (as my images there are loaded)
2. add the following line in the `assets.rb`:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\..*/]
   ```

but nothing worked.

Could you advise anything else to try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does `ls public/assets` outputs in production?

Probably your files are there with a digest (ex. `fontello-XXXX.ttf`). In this case you have to use the [font helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-font_path) in your sass (not css) - ex. in your font-family block: `src:font-url('fontello.ttf')`